# Do premium domain names help us with other languages too?

Tags: search-engines, seo, local-seo

It's commonly known that premium domains with one or two relevant keywords may help us improve our rankings in SERPS.

But would it be possible that an english premium domain, for example gold.com (no, it's not mine) also helps to drive more non-english traffic (I'm talking about non-english pages ob)?

### Trying to make my question clear:

Let's suppose that I have an english premium domain with a page like this:

gold dot com/post/123/gold-is-yellow

And decide to have a spanish, portuguese or french version of the site with pages like:

- gold dot com/es/post/123/el-oro-es-amarillo
- gold dot com/pt/post/123/o-ouro-e-amarelo
- gold dot com/fr/post/123/fsdfsdfsdf

The fact that my english domain is a premium one and highly relevant for english terms, will also help me to achieve good rankings for non-english searched terms like:
oro (spanish) or ouro (portuguese)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a foreign word in the domain (e.g. `ouro.com`) is unlikely to show search results for an English word (e.g. `gold`) even if it is a direct translation. The oppposite is true as well - `gold.com` would not give the "domain boost" when searching for `ouro`.

Note: You can still rank perfectly well for those terms since you can have keywords in the rest of the URL and on the page. The only difference is the domain name does not contribute to the ranking.

Additional notes:

- It's possible that if lots of people searched for one term then the other, Google may pick it up as a spelling correction or synonym. Spelling corrections only happen if one keyword has a much higher number of results than the one searched for. And there are not many people who will search for a word, and then the English translation.
- Having keywords in the domain does help, whatever the language. So `ouro.com` would be likely to rank high for `ouro`. Preferably one would also use a country-specific TLD (.co.uk for UK, .de for Germany, etc) to get better local rankings.
- The exact match domain boost isn't a massive boost so it's better to focus on content. Using a more unique domain/site name can also help in branding.

Comment: You mean that search engines pick that gold in english is the same as oro, ouro or or in spanish, portuguese or french? And therefore gold.com becomes relevant for the non-english content?

Comment: Oh... I think I misread the question. I meant that gold would rank well for English users and ouro would rank well for non-English searches.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but now I am a bit confused. Certainly my question wasn't clear, so I updated it. Please take a look at it and help me understand the answer so that I can it mark it as the correct.

Comment: @FabioMilheiro to answer the update: no, the domain `gold.com` would not rank higher for `ouro`. But as I said in my answer it's not a big deal. You would have keywords in the rest of the URL and on the page so that would be the main factor.